# Cant use resource packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm using Linux Ubuntu 14 and I have my desired texture pack but when i go to .minecraft it doesn't show a texture pack folder so I am unable to download resource packs what do I do to fix it? I already tried doing a re download but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best method of opening a texture pack on the Linux OS is to:

**1.** Download a resource pack, you should get a .zip file

**2.** Open the folder to which you downloaded the file

**3.** Copy the .zip file

**4.** Type ~/.minecraft/resourcepacks/ in your file manager's address bar or in the
console

**5.** Paste the file into the directory

**6.** Open Minecraft

**7.** Go to "Options", then "Resource Packs"

**Final:** The resource pack should now be listed and you can activate it by choosing it and hitting "Done".

[Source 1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Loading_a_resource_pack)

Comment: The problem is is that there is no resource pack folder

Comment: I just tried your theory and it didn't work

Comment: This isn't a theory, it's the official minecraft way of adding texture packs on Linux. I believe you can add a folder for texture packs manually, by creating it in the correct folder.

Comment: So I can do all of this, but the texture pack doesn't actually apply in-game. I can select it in the "texture packs" window in the Minecraft menu, but no game textures actually change. I'm on Minecraft 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04